# PL/SQL procedure to compare 3 employees' salary, then swap the lowest and highest salary

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm looking to have a procedure that takes in 3 employee_id's as parameters then compares them, the lowest and highest will be swapped while the middle one is left alone. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly, I keep getting errors on oracle apex in the if else section. I've read maybe implementing a case statement could be easier? 
--Note: this is a homework question
What I have so far:

```
create or replace procedure myproc(empid in number, empid in number, empid in number) is
  originalsalary1   employees.salary%type;
  originalsalary2   employees.salary%type;
  originalsalary3   employees.salary%type;
  newsalary         employees.salary%type;
begin
  select salary INTO originalsalary1 from employees
  where employee_id = empid;
  select salary INTO originalsalary2 from employees
  where employee_id = empid;
  select salary INTO originalsalary3 from employees
  where employee_id = empid;
  if originalsalary1 <= originalsalary2 and originalsalary3 then
    newsalary := originalsalary1 * 1.1; 
  elseif originalsalary2 <= originalsalary1 and originalsalary3 then
    newsalary := originalsalary2 * 1.1;
  elseif originalsalary3 <= originalsalary1 and originalsalary2 then
    newsalary := originalsalary3 * 1.1;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: This isn't the full answer but it looks like you are using the same variable name for all three employee ids. Shouldn't they be empid1, empid2, empid3?

Comment: Your and clause looks wrong to me. 'and originalsalary3' in most languages would either fail or evaluate to true for all values other than 0

Comment: The procedure also looks like it's not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_PREP(EMPID1 IN INT, EMPID2 IN INT , EMPID3 IN 
INT)
 IS
 MAX_SAL_EMP_ID INT;
 MIN_SAL_EMP_ID INT;
 MAX_SAL EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
 MIN_SAL EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
 BEGIN
   SELECT EMP_ID , SALARY INTO MAX_SAL_EMP_ID , MAX_SAL FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 
    EMP_ID IN (EMPID1, EMPID2, EMPID3)
    AND SALARY = (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID IN (EMPID1, 
   EMPID2, EMPID3));

   SELECT EMP_ID , SALARY INTO MIN_SAL_EMP_ID , MIN_SAL FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 
    EMP_ID IN (EMPID1, EMPID2, EMPID3)
    AND SALARY = (SELECT MIN(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID IN (EMPID1, 
    EMPID2, EMPID3));

    UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = MAX_SAL WHERE EMP_ID = MIN_SAL_EMP_ID;
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = MIN_SAL WHERE EMP_ID = MAX_SAL_EMP_ID;
    COMMIT;
   END;
```